# C: Passing a function pointer in a function it is passed to

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a mapping function that takes a function pointer, and passes it to another function, but gcc is yelling at me.

Here is an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
void map(T thing, void apply(int a, int b, void *cl), void *cl);

void function(T thing, void apply(int a, int b, void *cl), void * cl)
{

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {

      map(thing, apply, cl);

   }

}
```

gcc's complaint:

> warning: passing argument 2 of 'map' from incompatible pointer type

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the signature of `map`?

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me, with gcc 4.3.4 (after providing some typedef T). Are you sure you have posted the **exact** code that gives the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that's the declaration for `map`? Now I can't reproduce the problem ... it works

Comment: Well, it's for a class, so I can't post the exact code, but I found out what was wrong, the apply functions took a different "T" for each type of map function. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In order to help with this problem we'd need to see the declaration / signature of the map function.  Almost certainly there is a slight difference in the function signature.  The easiest way to resolve this is to typedef out a function pointer type and use it in both functions.

```
typedef void (*apply)(int,int,void*);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass functions around. You need to pass pointers to functions instead.

```
void map(T thing, void (*apply)(int a, int b, void *cl), void *cl);
void function(T thing, void (*apply)(int a, int b, void *cl), void * cl)
{
    /* ... */
    map(thing, apply, cl);
    /* .... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just complaining that the function pointer type expected by `map`'s second argument is different from that of `apply`. If you either change that type, or (if safe) cast, then it'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with gcc 4.3.3 and `-Wall`.

While I think all versions of C that ever existed rewrote function "value" parameters to be pointers, you could use a more traditional declaration:

```
void function(T thing, void (*f)(int a, int b, void *cl), void * cl)
```

But, like I said, your example works fine for me, unchanged except for `typedef int T`, and `map(1, ...)`